# Using django-facebook to display text on facebook canvas

Tags: python, django, django-facebook

I am practicing using django-facebook to integrate my django app with facebook and turn it into a facebook app. The documentation for django-facebook is very bad but I have managed to get my sample app to load the facebook canvas page. But I am unable to display anything on the canvas page.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated. Sorry if this question is a little vague or unclear. Please let me know if I can clarify something.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Currently I only have docs up about using django facebook for registration purposes.
First im improving testing for the project.
Afterwards I'll have some tutorial on how to use it for apps.
But you could pretty much start from the facebook documentation (they have an example project.) and look at the example canvas view in views.py

Django Facebook
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Canvas Views
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/blob/master/django_facebook/views.py

Facebook example project

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/

Comment: Thierry, any news on this example? Can you please clarify if djangp_facebook has already support for canvas application or if it's not finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, very though question.
As first advice i suggest you to be sure that you have SSL enabled on the webserver that serve the canvas service.
After that you will able to serve static files as canvas page, but not a django view. It is possible but i'm not able to find a workaround.